# How can i use scanner and tokens?

Tags: java, user-input, token, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

i have already asked about how can i split the user's input using tokens but i want to split it using the scanner class in order to use each token separately ...

example...
suppose that we have this input : what time is it

When i split it to tokens, i want to store it somewhere ( array of strings or specific variables ) in order to use each word for if statements ...

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.util.StringTokenizer;

     public class Main_Loop_Tokens {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    String temp;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("PROMPT:>> ");
        temp = scanner.nextLine();

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(temp);

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

            if (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                String Word1 = st.nextToken();

                if (Word1.equals("what")) {
                    String Word2 = st.nextToken();
                                       if (Word2.equals("time"){
                                            System.out.println("bla bla bla");
```

In this code actually i am trying to do that with tokenizer but it is so complicated because i want just to store them somewhere no matter how many they are. Now if i enter 1 word only its done !!!

```
         String Word1="the first token"
         String Word2="the second token"
         String Word3="the third token"
```

depends on how many they are.

```
   if (word1.equals("something")){ 
    // do something 
   }

   if (word2.equals("something2")){
    // do something else
   }
```

that is why i found out that it is easier to use scanner tokens but i do not know how ... thank you !!!

Comment: Ok, not related to question, String comparison should use equals() instead of == (except String literal comparison)

Comment: Scanner will split `something else` into two words by default (unless you use nextLine())

Comment: it is just to show you what i am trying to do ... but thank you ,you were all right !!!